# Elasticsearch: How do I exclude counting some of the fields while keeping the log from being filtered out?

Tags: elasticsearch

I hope the question is not very vague....

I have bunch of logs in ES, and I'm trying to aggregate the sum of a specific field, in this case, `file`, the mapping is

`http://localhost:9200/set_1/record/_mapping`

```
"properties": {
    "tags": {"type":"object","dynamic":false,"properties":{
                "all":{"type":"string","analyzer":"my_analyzer","store":"true"},
                "some_other_stuff_that's_not_important":.....
    },
    "file": {"type":"nested","dynamic":"false","include_in_root":"true","properties":{
                "doctype":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed","include_in_all":"false"},
                "some_other_stuff": {....}
    }
```

so right now I want to filter everything with a `tag` called `download`, and I want to count the number of `file` in those filtered logs

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "tags.all": "Downloaded"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now, the `file` will be a list of different files included in this log, and I want to know how to aggregate if I want to count all of the files but excluding certain file type like, say, `.docx`

How should I form the aggregation query?

Answer (score 0):

So I aggregated with key=`file.type`, and I put an `exclude` arg in the aggregation query, making it exclude=["type1", "type2"] where type 1 and 2 are different file types

This is for ES 1.7 by the way.